# Facebook Android application is unable to accept the EXTRA_TEXT fields

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, share-intent

**When using the built-in Android sharing module, the Facebook Android application is unable to accept the EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_TEXT fields.**

```
  val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)
  sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"@getyoteam")
  sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files )
  sharingIntent.type = "image/* "
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"))
```

Comment: Could you put some reproducible code or some logs?